# Getting warning when installing packages via yarn for unmet peer dependencies even though they are added in node modules

Tags: yarnpkg

## System:

- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.5
- CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
- Memory: 50.37 MB / 8.00 GB
- Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh

  ### Binaries:
- Node: 12.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node
- Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
- npm: 6.12.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/npm

  ### npmPackages:
- babel-plugin-styled-components: ^1.10.6 => 1.10.6
- styled-components: ^5.0.0-rc.1 => 5.0.0-rc.1

Why I am getting this warning, even though I can see packages in node_modules

```
yarn add eslint-config-airbnb                                                     
yarn add v1.19.1
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "eslint-config-airbnb > eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-import@^2.18.2".
warning " > eslint-config-airbnb@18.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-import@^2.18.2".
warning " > eslint-config-airbnb@18.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.2.3".
warning " > eslint-config-airbnb@18.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^1.7.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 3 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ eslint-config-airbnb@18.0.1
info All dependencies
├─ confusing-browser-globals@1.0.9
├─ eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.0.0
└─ eslint-config-airbnb@18.0.1
✨  Done in 3.24s.
```

```
yarn add styled-components@beta
yarn add v1.19.1
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "styled-components > stylis-rule-sheet@0.0.10" has unmet peer dependency "stylis@^3.5.0".
warning " > styled-components@5.0.0-rc.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-is@>= 16.8.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ styled-components@5.0.0-rc.1
info All dependencies
└─ styled-components@5.0.0-rc.1
✨  Done in 3.19s.
```